# Интеграция Carrot quest с Retail CRM

Tags: php, битрикс

Настраиваю интеграцию по этой инструкции
https://help.carrotquest.io/hc/ru/articles/360000343912
Интеграция в Carrotquest добавилась, так же после `carrotquest.connect('');` в хедере добавил `carrotquest.auth('Тут ID пользователя', 'тут хеш');`

Но работать оно почему-то не хочет, регистрировал нового пользвателя и в Retail по-прежнему "Новые клиенты 0" и вообще все пусто. В чем может быть проблема?
Сам сайт на Bitrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интеграции Carrot quest и RetailCRM работает по такому принципу - по контактам (e-mail, телефон, Carrot ID) лид ищется в Retail, если его не находит, то создаётся новый клиент в Retail. User ID участвует только при создании лида и не участвует в поиске.

Возможные варианты почему не создается лид (считаем, что User ID у него записался):

- В RetailCRM уже есть клиент с таким User ID, при этом В Carrot quest нет емейла и телефона, либо они отличаются от таковых в Retail (т.е. Carrot банально не смог найти такого клиента в Retail) - в этой ситуации приходит отказ от Retail, так как такой пользователь уже существует (привязка по User ID)
- У лида в Carrot записан email, но он не проходит валидацию в Retail (например там записано "test") - в этой ситуации приходит отказ от Retail из-за формата e-mail

Скорее всего, у вас первая ситуация. В принципе должна решиться, если у лида емейл будет записываться ДО отправки в RetailCRM.